# Does node's event loop mean that I need to rethink user variable storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just hit an area of confusion thinking about the way that node is serving each user..

From my limited understanding, with PHP,a new (thread?) environment was created for each user, so my script only needed to focus on one individual user and that would apply to each individual.

Now, from my very limited understanding of node, one event loop is handling all of my users. So in this script snippet for example,

```
//imaginary script to validate user's post to server (log-in attempt) next:

console.log('user logged in successfully!');

var username =  req.body.username;

//imaginary script that takes the username and processes it somehow, using my username variable
```

If another user has logged in since the last user, the `username` variable will have been overwritten, and now everything is messed up. Whereas with PHP, when a new user connected, he'd be handled with a new, reset environment..

That may not be exactly right, but what I think I'm seeing is that I need to keep ALL of the user-associated data on the client side, and pass everything between the client and server as a package, not keeping any user data stored server-side.

Am I on track here, completely confused, or is there a better way to think about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the scope of the variable (where it was created). Consider this simple and simplified example:

```
var http = require('http');

var variableOne = "foobar";

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var variableTwo = "barfoo";

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

`variableOne` is sort of global, since the node.js will go though the declaration of the variable only once during start up time. The variable is available everywhere in the scipt so it could be changed by every request/user.

`variableTwo` is created for every request that node.js handles. It is possible, that there are multiple versions of this variable.

When handling permant user data you need to store it some way it is accessible on a later request but unique for the user.

Again a simplified example:

```
var http = require('http');

var userData = {};

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    userData[request.connection.remoteAddress] = "some unique user data";

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

It will save `some unique user data` per IP address. You can read the data later by checking if the IP address was used before. This is not very practical but should give you an idea. In a real world example you would generate an unique cookie per user.

Comment: Right, but my variables are only good for storing user data for one process(function call), so that means once my function is processed, I need to assume that all variables are unknown/overwritten.

Comment: Oh wow.. I almost ended that last sentence in an ; ... too much javascript today lol.

Comment: Because you are coming from the PHP world I would assume you like to some HTML page stuff? If yes take a look at [express.js](http://expressjs.com/).

Comment: Ok, so I can store dynamic user data for the length of the server being online.. But for simplicity, shouldn't I not do that? Seems like it would be more work than it's worth to write the scripting to handle the possibility of a server crash/restart. Keeping all the data packaged in each ajax call where it's required may be more load on the server, but seems safer in terms of simplicity. You did answer my question though. I've got the right idea

Comment: Oh yes, I was introduced to Express right away in Node though I dont know exactly what it is. I've just used it through tutorials

Comment: Of course you can store the data permanently. You should need to save it is somewhere (file system, database) if you want it to survive a server restart,

Comment: Right, a database storage. When I said dynamic user data, I meant data being processed, thrown somewhere, and then grabbed again.

Comment: One clarification worth making is that Javascript variables are function scoped, not block-scoped. Given that so much is done with callbacks, the blocks are often functions but if you have (e.g.) a for loop and declare a variable inside that loop, it is available outside of the loop but inside whatever function contains the loop. Hence the practice many have of declaring all variables in a function at the top of the function, rather than the more generally common (in other languages) practice of declaring at first use.